# console log4j2 kafka: No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)

Tags: scala, maven, logging, apache-kafka, log4j2

I'm trying to get `Kafka` simply `logging` through the `console`, but after installing my sw I just keep seeing this error.

My `log4j2.xml`:

https://pastebin.com/gqyN1Fsi

my `pom.xml` includes this dependencies:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.12.:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.12.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api-scala_2.12:jar:11.0:compile
```

my main class is a very simple consumer:

```scala
   class Consumer(val brokers: String,
              val groupId: String,
              val topic: String) extends Logging {
 

 val props: Properties = createConsumerConfig(brokers, groupId)
 val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, User] = new KafkaConsumer[String, User](props)
 var executor: ExecutorService = _

 def shutdown() = {
   if (consumer != null)
     consumer.close()
   if (executor != null)
     executor.shutdown()
 }

 def createConsumerConfig(brokers: String, groupId: String): Properties = {
   val props = new Properties()
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId)
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true")
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000")
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000")
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "kafka.UserDeserializer")
   props
 }


 def run(): Unit = {
   consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topic))

   Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor.execute(() => {
     while (true) {
       val records: ConsumerRecords[String, User] = consumer.poll(ofMillis(1000))
       records
         .forEach(r => {
           
           logger.info("Received message: (" + r.key() + ", " + r.value() + ") at offset " + r.offset())
         })
     }
   })
 }
```

So, when i `package` my app and `run` through command line `java -jar`, the first few lines are:

```scala
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried a lot of dependency version combinations and I've tried to change my `log4j2.xml` into a `log4j2.properties` but I've never managed to register this `logger` :<

Please suggest me the way to achieve the simplest log!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, is very simple

`maven dependency`

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
```

imports in your code

```scala
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

initialize your logs

```scala
    private void run() {
        // logger
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerDemoWithThread.class.getName());
```

track the process with logs

```scala
       // add a shutdown hook
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread( () -> {
            logger.info("Caught shutdown hook"); // log
            ((ConsumerRunnable) myConsumerRunnable).shutdown();
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            logger.info("Application has exited"); // log
        }));

        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Application got interrupted", e); // log
        } finally {
            logger.info("Application is closing");  // log
        }
    }
```

I hope, it gives you some clues. Regards.